# Office 365 Admin functions programmatically (Graph, REST or powershell)

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, office365, office365api, office365-apps

We want to **programmatically** perform a number of miscellaneous Office 365 Administration functions for our clients.

**Can anyone tell me which is the more comprehensive or flexible way forward between the following when used ONLY programmatically?:**

1. Powershell (powershell commands run in .Net through library or otherwise)
2. The [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/)
3. The [Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview)

*NB:  I'm mostly concerned with which approach has the most coverage in terms of available functionality, however, ease of use is also a factor that I'm considering also*

Comment: I think it'll depend on what operations you are looking to do, can you give us some concrete examples?

Like many things the lower level you go the more comprehensive options you have, but the more boiler plate you have to write.

You mention running powershell through .net which seems a little convoluted, you may wish to look for .net SDKs instead?

Comment: Thanks @AlexKeySmith  Im not a .net guru by any means.  I just know that I want to have a good programmatic handle on calling powershell commands.  I assumed that .Net would offer this but I may be mistaken.  What SDK did you have in mind.  I will fish you up some examples of calls we need to make

Comment: Cool, if you're familiar with powershell probably easiest to stick with powershell throughput and jump into c# if you find it doesn't give you enough power / you need your code embedded into something else e.g. a web app. In terms of SDK, I don't have a particular one in mind, but doing a quick search (I'm no authority), GraphAPI has a c# SDK: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet

Comment: Thanks @AlexKeySmith.  I worry that Graph API is too new and that it wont have the full functionality yet, let alone any good admin functionality.  Im a Linux Java guy so powershell is alien to me, however Ill try anything.  I need to run it through a high level langauges such as .Net, Java or Node so that I can expose the calls as REST endpoints.  As such powershell alone wont cut it. At very least I will need to call one of these 3 options to interact with Office365 ADMIN from one of these languages

Comment: I see ok, so you're looking to expose your code back out. If you're familiar with Java, c# will likely be your friend. But PowerShell will have a good ecosystem for Active Directory, as it's made for automating "stuff". You can use an Azure Automation Account which can host powershell and expose it back out as callable endpoints. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/  I haven't used microsoft graph api directly, but this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api suggests that it's superseding the Azure AD Graph API.

Comment: Thanks @AlexKeySmith